# Google cloud vision API error reading pdf

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I am currently trying to process a large pdf document using google cloud vision API. When reading the document I am receiving an error that says "json_format.Parse( error". I have attached my code below. How can I fix this?
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ3ml.png)

Comment: Please post your code in text format so it can be easily reproduced by community members. Also include the full stacktrace of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error on that line of code because you are trying to pass `json_string` with **type: <class 'bytes'>** and a non existent object `vision.types.AnnotateFilesResponse()` to [json_format.Parse()](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/json_format.html#google.protobuf.json_format.Parse) that requires:

> google.protobuf.json_format.Parse(text, message,ignore_unknown_fields=False, descriptor_pool=None) Parses a JSON
> representation of a protocol message into a message.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - text – Message JSON representation.
> - message – A protocol buffer message to merge into.
> - ignore_unknown_fields – If True, do not raise errors for unknown fields.
> - descriptor_pool – A Descriptor Pool for resolving types. If None use
>   the default.
>
> Returns The same message passed as argument.
>
> Raises:: ParseError: On JSON parsing problems.

Since your goal is to read the response from your `async_batch_annotate_files()`, the JSON response from this method will be saved to the defined Cloud Storage Bucket output location. You can just read and parse the data in `json_string` by converting it to a dictionary. You can then work you way in the dictionary by referring to [AnnotateFileResponse reference](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/BatchAnnotateFilesResponse#AnnotateFileResponse). using the code below:

```
output = blob_list[0]
json_string = output.download_as_string()
response = json.loads(json_string)
first_page_response = response['responses'][0]
annotation = first_page_response['fullTextAnnotation']

print('Full text:\n')
print(annotation['text'])
```

NOTE: Just make sure that you are getting the correct JSON response file (`output = blob_list[0]`), else the parsing of results will yield and error.